# Type mismatch for a simple secure social play 2 app

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, securesocial

I'm trying to implement a very simple play app based on the securesocial sample on based on [this demo](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/tree/master/samples/scala/demo).

```
play 2.2.2 built with Scala 2.10.3 (running Java 1.7.0_45)
```

However, I'm getting a [compile](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/samples/scala/demo/app/views/index.scala.html#L60) error.

Compilation error

```
type mismatch; found : String("/link-result") required: Int
In /Users/ssimanta/demo-play-auth/app/views/index.scala.html at line 60.
57    @Registry.providers.all.values.map { provider =>
58        @if( provider.authMethod == OAuth1 || provider.authMethod == OAuth2 ) {
59            @defining( "securesocial/images/providers/%s.png".format(provider.id) ) { imageUrl =>
60            <a href="@provider.authenticationUrl("/link-result")"> <img src="@RoutesHelper.at(imageUrl)"/></a> 
61        }
62        }
63    }
64    </span>
65    <hr>
```

Comment: i have the save environment, but compiles perfectly

Answer (score 1):

**Your double-quotes around the path are not escaped.**

Try this:

```
"""@provider.authenticationUrl("/link-result")"""
```

or:

```
"@provider.authenticationUrl('/link-result')"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, it had nothing to do with quotes: I was referencing `2.1.4` instead of `2.1.x-SNAPSHOT` in my build `.sbt` file. The latter `SecureSocial` release has support for provider linking and defines in `module-code/app/securesocial/core/IdentityProvider.scala`:

```
def authenticationUrl(redirectTo: String): String = RoutesHelper.authenticate(id, Some(redirectTo)).url
```